# Is "chaqu'un" an acceptable form of "chacun", or is it not a real word? From what is "chacun" derived?

Tags: étymologie, pronoms, orthographe

Instead of "chacun", is it OK to write "chaqu'un" or is that not a real word?

Is "chacun" derived from or a simplified form for "chaqu'un" (chaque un), i.e. "each one", or not?

Comment: Could you tell us where you found this spelling?

Comment: @victor Just in some informal personal writing, not published.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word is *[chacun](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chacun)*. The word *[chaque](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaque)* is always spelled with the final `e` anyway. I'm surprised to find so many [Google hits for `chaqu'un`](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22chaqu'un%22); I wouldn't have thought it to be a common spelling error.

Etymologically speaking, *chacun* is related to *chaque*, but it is not a contraction of *chaqu'un*. It's rather the opposite, in fact. The word *chacun* comes from the vulgar Latin  word *cascunum* (with a similar meaning), which in turn seems to be a cross between *quisque unus* (“each one”) and *unum cata unum* (“one by one”). The contraction into one word happened back in Latin, not in French. The word *chaque* arose later, in Old French, as a derivative of *chascun* (as it was then spelled), by analogy with *quelque* and *quelqu'un*.

If you look at published books, you'll see that there is no contest: the spelling is *chacun*.

[image: chacun, chaqu'un]

The only occurrences of *chaqu'un* are in older texts (early 19th century is the most recent I could find), and there are very few of these. So I would say that it's an old spelling error, but a spelling error nonetheless.

Looking at some [old dictionaries](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=chacun), I find no mention of a recognized variant spelling. [Féraud's dictionary](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=chacun#CHACUN) does list *chaqun* as an incorrect spelling for *chacun*.

Looking at modern usage, the [Leipzig corpus](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/ws_fra/) (which includes many newspapers and websites such as Wikipedia) has very few occurrences of *chaqu*. The usage examples are striking by the number of other, uncontroversial spelling errors they contain. So I feel confident in dismissing *chaqu'un* as incorrect, even under the most descriptivist approach.

Answer (score 6):

Like everyone else said *chaqu'un* doesn't exist.

*Chacun* comes from old French *"chascun"* which in turn comes from the Vulgar Latin word ***cascúnum*** (a crossing of *"quisque(unus)"*, that literally means "every one" = « chaque un ») and ***catúnum*** (from [*unum*] *cata<sup>1</sup> unum*), literally « un à un »).

You can read more about it on the CNRTL site definition for *"[chacun](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chacun)"*.

---

<sup>1: It comes from Greek κατά *"exprimant une notion de temps, avec idée de distribution: κατἐνιαυτόυ « chaque année »"*</sup>

Answer (score 5):

"chaqu'un" doesn't exists at all in French language. The unique construct is "chacun" (or "chacune" for the female form), translated to "each one".
The word came from ancient French "chascun", which is derived from the Latin "cascunum".

Answer (score 5):

*chaqu'un* is not a real word and must not be used.

*chacun* seems to be originating from a contraction of latin roots of *chaque un* and *un à un*. ([wiktionary.org](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chacun))